# How to check the cell value of other workbook is empty or not in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim ConsolidateSheetObj As Workbook
Dim str As String
Dim keycount,row As Interger

Set ConsolidateSheetObj = Workbooks.open("filePath")

Set str = ConsolidateSheetObj.Sheets(3).Cells(row, 17 + keycount).Value

If str.IsEmpty() Then
. . .
...

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Coercing to a string and checking its length is a poor way to do this. Additionally, your using `Set str` is syntatically invalid: `Set` is only used for object types.

A better way is:

```
Dim v as Variant
v = ConsolidateSheetObj.Sheets(3).Cells(row, 17 + keycount).Value
If VarType(v) = vbEmpty Then
    'this is an empty range
End If
```

Comment: I tried this by giving str As Variant, when I run the code it is throwing "Type Mismatch" error

Comment: Yes you would do. Your code will error if the range cannot be coerced to a string.

Comment: when I tried to print the output of "ConsolidateSheetObj.Sheets(3).Cells(row, 17 + keycount).Value" with MsgBox it is showing blank if the cell is empty, otherwise it showing the string that cell contained.

Comment: could you tell me what is the return type of "ConsolidateSheetObj.Sheets(3).Cells(row, 17 + keycount).Value"

Comment: ok, when i'm trying this 
Dim str As Variant
Set str = ConsolidateSheetObj.Sheets(3).Cells(row, 17 + keycount).Value

it is throwing type mismatch error.
Is there any other way to check whether the cell is empty or not

Comment: Now you're using the `Set` keyword improperly. Leave it out: you're taking a value copy so to have it is a syntax error.

Comment: could you what is the mistake I'm doing

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub checkEmpty()
    'Used variables
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim sheet, row, keycount As Integer
    Dim cellEmpty As Boolean

    'Disable Screen updates
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    filePath = "C:\Your_file.xlsx"
    sheet = 3
    row = 3
    keycount = 2
    cellEmpty = False

    'Open other workbook
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        filePath
    'Check if cell is empty
    If isEmpty(Sheets(sheet).Cells(row, 17 + keycount)) Then
        cellEmpty = True
    End If

    'Close other workbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=No

    If cellEmpty Then
        MsgBox ("Cell is Empty!")
        '...Your Code here!
    End If

    'Enable Screen updates
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 better than my solution since it avoids expensive coercion to `Variant`.

Comment: When I use use like this
ConsolidateSheetObj.Sheets(3).Cells(row, 17 + keycount).Value.IsEmpty()

It is throwing object required error

Comment: Added your `row` and `keycount` variables

Comment: row = 3,
keycount = 2

Comment: Could you already solve your problem? Just updated my answer with some more extended code and doc...